# Solving a very large system of non-linear equations (numerically) with a unique solution

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-equation

I have encountered a **very large system of non-linear equations** which looks like:

- M'UM = A
- M'VM = B

where M, U, V are unknown `d*d` matrices, and A and B are known `d*d` matrices with the following properties:

- U and V are diagonal matrices
- The principal diagonal entries of M are all 1's
- A and B are symmetric matrices, and their entries are known
- M' denotes the transpose of M.

Note that both the total number of (non-linear) equations and the total number of unknown variables are same, viz. d(d+1) to be precise. So, it ensures that **this system possesses a unique solution.**

I was trying to solve this system numerically in `R` using packages like `nleqslv` and `BB`. But their documentations do not cover instances where the unknowns are inputted in terms of matrices. In the worst case, we can write all the equations by hand, and make use of the aforementioned packages. However, I am looking for a better method.

Any help will be appreciated. Even if someone suggests some other programming language or software that might help in this regard, that'll be fine too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution to this problem. Specifically, I found a way to find a solution to M'UM = A, given A, assuming that A is a symmetric matrix.

Specifically, every real symmetric matrix can be written in the form

[image: X = QDQ transpose]

where Q is formed from an orthonormal set of eigenvectors of X and the diagonal of D contains the corresponding eigenvalues.

[Source.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860643/decomposing-square-matrix-into-two-matrices-which-are-transposes-of-each-other/2860686#2860686)

Using numpy, it's pretty easy to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

```py
def solve(A):
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(A)
    M = eigenvectors
    U = np.diag(eigenvalues)
    M_prime = M.T
    return M, U, M_prime
```

Then, I tried this on a random symmetric array:

```py
A = np.array([[0.2777055 , 0.17491669, 0.22634241],
       [0.17491669, 0.94572725, 0.4859058 ],
       [0.22634241, 0.4859058 , 0.89480942]])

M, U, M_prime = solve(A)
M @ U @ M_prime
```

Result:

```py
array([[0.2777055 , 0.17491669, 0.22634241],
       [0.17491669, 0.94572725, 0.4859058 ],
       [0.22634241, 0.4859058 , 0.89480942]])
```

Sure enough, when you multiply those three matricies together, you get back the original A.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve this in a way that satisfies both equations.